# How to upload video to Brightcove through API with PHP and Curl

Tags: php, curl, brightcove

I am trying to upload a video to Brightcove using the `create_video` method from their API. All of their examples show how to do it from an image that has been submitted from a form. I need to do it with images that are already on the server though. I think I'm quite close but I keep getting the following error:

```
{"error": {"name":"RequiredParameterError","message":"create_video requires a filestream or remote asset references","code":303}, "result": null, "id": null}1
```

Here is my code:

```
$data = array(
    'method' => "create_video",
    'params' => array(
        'video' => array(
            'name' => $video->filename,
            'referenceId' => $video->id,
            'shortDescription' => 'Sample video'
        ),
        "token" => $this->config->item('brightcove_write_token'), 
        "encode_to" => "MP4",
        "create_multiple_renditions" => "True",
    ),
    'filename' => $video->filename,
    'file' => FCPATH.'assets/uploads/submitted/'.$video->filename
);                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);    

$url = 'http://api.brightcove.com/services/post';
$fields = array(
    'json' => $data_string
);

//url-ify the data for the POST
$fields_string='';
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted it in the end, json had to be one parameter and then file had to be another like so:

```
$data = array(
    'method' => "create_video",
    'params' => array(
        'video' => array(
            'name' => $video->filename,
            'shortDescription' => 'Sample video'
        ),
        "token" => $this->config->item('brightcove_write_token'), 
        "encode_to" => "MP4",
        "create_multiple_renditions" => "True"
    ),
);                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);    

$url = 'http://api.brightcove.com/services/post';
$fields = array(
    'json' => $data_string,
    'file' => new CURLFile(FCPATH.'assets/uploads/submitted/'.$video->filename)
);

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//execute post
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
```

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
'file' => FCPATH.'assets/uploads/submitted/'.$video->filename
```

results in POSTing the `file` field with its value being the full path to your video file's name.

To get cURL to post it as an actual file upload, prefix the path with an `@` like so:

```
'file' => '@' . FCPATH.'assets/uploads/submitted/'.$video->filename
```

If you are using PHP 5.5 or greater, you should use a `CURLFile` object for the upload field:

```
'file' => new CURLFile(FCPATH.'assets/uploads/submitted/'.$video->filename)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I still get the same error though

Comment: I can't find their API documentation so not sure how to proceed.  The JSON encoded data string will actually make the upload field not work (I just noticed that after I posted my answer).  Does their API expect you to provide a URL to the video which they then download?

Comment: This is the URL to the API doc http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/media/references/reference.html#Video_Write

Comment: It says For write requests, the data submitted to the media write API must be in JSON format, encoded as a form parameter named "json". The JSON document should include a "method" field and a "params" field

Comment: I see you got it, your code is correct.  The `file` input needs to be it's own form element outside of the JSON.

Comment: Thanks for all your help its much appreciated